# Dynamic Grid generation from a Generic Collection Devexpres grid Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I use Devexpress grid at present it using templated columns like such in Xamarin.Forms

```
<dxg:DataGridView x:Name="dgWeightLifting" AutoFilterRowHeight="100"  
     ShowAutoFilterRow="True" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"           
PullToRefresh="dgWeightLifting_PullToRefresh"  

     DoubleTap="dgWeightLifting_DoubleTap" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  
     HeightRequest="1000" >
        <dxg:DataGridView.CellStyle>
            <dxg:CellStyle  BackgroundColor="#333333" BorderColor="#515151"
             FontSize="14" FontColor="White" 
            SelectionColor="#f78a09" SelectionFontColor="Black"/>
        </dxg:DataGridView.CellStyle>

        <dxg:DataGridView.ColumnHeaderStyle >
            <dxg:ColumnHeaderStyle   BackgroundColor="#333333" BorderColor="#515151" 
             FontSize="16" FontColor="#929292" Padding="10,10,10,10" 
             FontAttributes="Bold" 
             HorizontalLineThickness="2"  />
        </dxg:DataGridView.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

//columns then start here which reference the fields in my list

```
<dxg:DataGridView.Columns >
 <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="15, 0, 0, 0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Item.TB, 
              StringFormat ='Weight: {0}'}" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
              <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding 
               Item.TBReps, StringFormat = 'Reps: {0}'}" 
               Grid.Row="2"></Label>
                </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
              </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
      </dxg:TemplateColumn>
</dxg:TemplateColumn>
</dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
</dxg:DataGridView>
```

As you can see their two fields for trap bar one weight and then reps one is of type integer and one of the decimal.

My question is to stop me from having to edit my XAML each time is there a way I can create a templated column from code? The control is from devexpress https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/400543/xamarin-forms/data-grid/index they don't offer support as free.

The reason I have them in a templated control to being with is cause I want some formatting abelites

[image]

Comment: https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/DevExpress.XamarinForms.DataGrid.DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumnsMode

Comment: @Jason that does not give me the formatting i want then i want the in the column stacked like that Autogenrated only allows u one value then

Comment: Maybe I misread.  Not sure why you would need to "edit the XAML each time" - each time what?  There is nothing to stop you from creating a data template like you would for each templated control.

Comment: I haven't tried to read your requirements in detail, but if you don't find a way to do it in xaml, then you could get more flexibility by writing it all in c#. First try to hand-translate a simple bit of xaml into c#. To get used to doing so. Next, hand-code the xaml for one column. Then get that to work as c#. Eventually you should see how to write c# that can build the whole grid according to your requirements. The benefit of c# code is that you can write methods that take parameters. Build up a library of small methods that do what you need.